# Failed to create Ubuntu virtual machine in Oracle Virtual Box on Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

I'm struggling to run 64bit Ubuntu on Oracle Virtual box, below are the details. Have been to many forums but none of the suggestions work for me. Hoping somebody here can help/advise.

I have AMD Ryzen 9 CPU, I have SVM (virtualization enabled in BIOS) MSI X570 - A PRO motherboard, Windows feature Hyper-V turned off.
OS Details below:
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 2004
Installed on    ‎12-‎11-‎2020
OS build    20257.1
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.27509.10291.0

Error when starting machine:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu20.

Failed to get device handle and/or partition ID for 00000000015f4340 (hPartitionDevice=0000000000000d00, Last=0xc0000002/1) (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

[image: VM Details Image]

Answer (score 2):

Considering the solution from [this thread](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18536) is for Insider Preview builds ( which I am on, and it fixed my issue ), even if you run on a stable w10 version, you could try disabling the following features from "Turn Windows features on or off":

```
Application Guard
Credential Guard
Device Guard
<any> Guard
Containers
Hyper-V
Virtual Machine Platform
Windows Hypervisor Platform
Windows Sandbox
Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your Virtualbox to `6.1.30`. It'll fix this issue. You can install Virtualbox from their [official website](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: Yes this worked for me, with Hyper-V enabled for WSL 2, and VB is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Turn Windows features on or off" settings (type optionalfeatures in the start menu or Win + R), and untick "Windows Sandbox". A couple reboots may be required.

[See here](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed)